# Rails Ajax Response includes Array of Entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

After several years finally I found my way back to Rails (6.1.4.4), and to regain my routine in programming with it, I implemented a little diary app, which was up and running within a day. For further exercise I started to implement all funcionality with XHR calls instead of HTML requests, which also went astonishlingly quick.

But now I went into a problem I don't even get my head around:

In my view I have two columns, to the left a list of diaries, to the right a list of entries. I hooked up every diary name with a link_to to get the entries of this diary and have it displayed in the right column. This is working fine now, but after the entries there is an array displayed, which contains all the entries that are displayed above it - just as if I ordered the view to display it with the 'inspect' method, like this:

> [#<Entry id: 3, title: "Reaktivierung meiner Programmierkenntnisse", content: "Seit ungefähr 10 Tagen arbeite ich nun am Ampel-Tr...", diary_id: 3, created_at: "2021-12-22 17:06:33.221409000 +0100", updated_at: "2021-12-22 17:06:33.221409000 +0100">, #<Entry id: 5, title: "Formular für Eintrag ausgebessert", content: "Jetzt ist endlich eine Select Box für die Auswahl ...", diary_id: 3, created_at: "2021-12-23 15:51:47.312066000 +0100", updated_at: "2021-12-23 15:51:47.312066000 +0100">, #<Entry id: 21, title: "Neuer Eintrag ist jetzt auf AJAX", content: "Wenn man den Button auf der Übersichtsseite verwen...", diary_id: 3, created_at: "2021-12-24 18:01:11.288181000 +0100", updated_at: "2021-12-24 18:01:11.288181000 +0100">]

I have absolutely no idea where this comes from!

The link to get the entries in my view is created by this:

```
<%= link_to diary.title, diary_path(diary), remote: true %>
```

Then in my diaries controller there is this show function:

```ruby
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
      format.js
    end
  end
```

show.js.erb

```js
$("#entries_container").html('<%= j render 'showentries' %>');
```

And finally in the partial 'showentries' I have the following:

```html
<%= @diary.entries.each do |entry| %>
    <div class="rounded entry_item" style="background-image: url('paper <%= entry.diary.id %>.jpg');">
        <div class="entry_headline">
        <span style="font-weight: 700;"><%= entry.title %></span>
        <span style="font-size:65%;font-style:italic;">(<%= entry.diary.title %>)</span>
        <span style="font-size:90%;"> - <%= entry.created_at.strftime("%-d.%-m.%Y") %> </span>
        <span style="font-size:70%;">(<%= entry.created_at.strftime("%H:%M") %>) </span>
        </div>
        <div class="entry_item_content listitem_<%= entry.diary.title.downcase %>">
        <%= simple_format(entry.content) %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I guess, that the array is somehow generated automatically by the server response, but why is it displayed, when I never asked for it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `<%= @diary.entries.each do |entry| %>` should be `<% @diary.entries.each do |entry| %>`. `<%= ... %>` puts the result on the page and `x.each` evaluates to `x`, `<% ... %>` just executes the code.

Comment: Of course! Couldn't spot this typo, even while writing this question! Thank you very much, it fixed the problem.